# Popup dialog that follow the mouse in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mouseevent, jquery-events

I'm using Angular 1.0.6 and jQuery and I need to create a hint that will follow the mouse (change position). What I have so far is the show/hide:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span ng-mouseover="item.show_description=true" ng-mouseleave="item.show_description=false">
       {{item.text}}
    </span>
    <div class="description-popup" ng-show="item.description && item.show_description">
       {{item.description}}
    </div>
</div>
```

How should I change x and y position of the popup depend on `mousemove` event? I was thinking that I could have something like this:

```
<div pointer="{x: item.x, y: item.y}">Hello</div>
<div class="popup" style="left: {{item.x}}; top: {{item: y}}">
  Popup
</div>
```

But don't know how to create directive like this.

Comment: There's already a tooltip plugin in AngularUI, but it doesn't follow the mouse http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip, also, consider upgrading to newer angular (already at 1.3)

Comment: @EliteOctagon I can't upgrade because I don't control the platform. also people that do want to upgrade but there is lot of code that will probably don't work and will need to be rewritten.

Comment: @EliteOctagon your link return 404 for me.

Comment: sorry, try http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ , see tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this utility that can be used as a service (it require $parse):

```
function objectParser(expr) {
    var strip = expr.replace(/\s*\{\s*|\s*\}\s*/g, '');
    var pairs = strip.split(/\s*,\s*/);
    if (pairs.length) {
        var getters = {};
        var tmp;
        for (var i=pairs.length; i--;) {
            tmp = pairs[i].split(/\s*:\s*/);
            if (tmp.length != 2) {
                throw new Error(expr + " is Invalid Object");
            }
            getters[tmp[0]] = $parse(tmp[1]);
        }
        return {
            assign: function(context, object) {
                for (var key in object) {
                    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        if (getters[key]) {
                            getters[key].assign(context, object[key]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function will parse values from object (string) as scope values, and returned object will allow to change those values based on other object. It can be used in directive like this:

```
{
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var expr = objectParser(attrs.pointer);
        element.mousemove(function(e) {
            var offest = element.offset();
            scope.$apply(function() {
                expr.assign(scope, {
                    x: e.pageX - offest.left,
                    y: e.pageY - offest.top
                });
            });
        });
    }
};
```