# ngShow don't work as expected when using custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I have this code in angular:

```
<span ng-mouseover="item.show_description=true" ng-mouseleave="item.show_description=false" pointer="{x: item.x, y: item.y}">
    {{item.label}}
</span>
<div class="description-popup" ng-show="!!item.description && item.show_description"
     style="left: {{item.x}}px; top: {{item.y}}px">
    <h2>{{item.label}}</h2>
    <p>{{item.description}}</p>
    <p>{{!!item.description && item.show_description}}</p>
</div>
```

It show popup correctly but if descritpion is null or empty string the popup still shows up. The last expression in that case show false. What I'm doing wrong here? Or maybe is there a bug there. I'm using Angular 1.0.6 (can't upgrade right now).

**UPDATE**:

I've create **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4822N/)** and it's seems that ng-show work as expected but not when I use pointer directive, that use mousemove event. The code for the directive is like this:

```
app.directive('pointer', function($parse) {
    function objectParser(expr) {
        var strip = expr.replace(/\s*\{\s*|\s*\}\s*/g, '');
        var pairs = strip.split(/\s*,\s*/);
        if (pairs.length) {
            var getters = {};
            var tmp;
            for (var i=pairs.length; i--;) {
                tmp = pairs[i].split(/\s*:\s*/);
                if (tmp.length != 2) {
                    throw new Error(expr + " is Invalid Object");
                }
                getters[tmp[0]] = $parse(tmp[1]);
            }
            return {
                assign: function(context, object) {
                    for (var key in object) {
                        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            if (getters[key]) {
                                getters[key].assign(context, object[key]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var expr = objectParser(attrs.pointer);
            element.mousemove(function(e) {
                var offest = element.offset();
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    expr.assign(scope, {
                        x: e.pageX - offest.left,
                        y: e.pageY - offest.top
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: Is it normal that you put two `!` before `item.description` ?

Comment: @R3tep that's how you convert values to boolean in JS. I wanted to be sure that it get bool value.

Comment: If you remove `!!`, there is the same behavior ?

Comment: @R3tep yes, I've got the same result.

Comment: Is it possible to create a live demo (with jsfiddle for example)? because your code seems fine.

Comment: @R3tep http://jsfiddle.net/4822N/ maybe it's something with my pointer because without it, it work.

Comment: Why don't you use `$parse` instead of your `objectParser`? `objectParser` only parses a small subset of what is possible. `$parse("{x: 1, y: 2}")` returns the object `{x: 1, y: 2}`. So you could remove `objectParser` and use `var expr = $parse(attrs.pointer);`.

Comment: @stevuu I use $parse but for values of object. If you can create better working pointer you can answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23500398/popup-dialog-that-follow-the-mouse-in-angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Isolate scope**

The problem is that `ng-show` uses the scope of the element it's on. If it's on an element that has a directive with isolate scope, then it will use that isolate scope, and not have access to the outside scope.

In this particular case, I suspect that `description-popup` has isolate scope, which means ng-show only has access to the scope of that directive, which probably doesn't have the `item` that you're trying to test against.

**What is isolate scope?**

Isolate scope means the directive has its own scope that does not inherit from the surrounding scope. Normal scopes inherit from the surrounding scopes, so they have access to the data on that surrounding scope. Isolate scope does not.

**Why would anyone ever want to use isolate scope?!**

Reuse. If a directive is intended to be reused in lots of places, in lots of different scopes with a variety of properties on them, you don't want properties on the directive's scope to collide with the properties of the surrounding scope. And since the directive is supposed to be totally independent and not use the surrounding scope at all, it's often a good idea to give it an isolate scope. There are very few disadvantages to this. Really, the only thing that's likely to go wrong is when someone wants to put an `ng-show` or `ng-hide` on that element.

**Solution**

Put your `ng-show` on an extra `<div>` around the `description-popup`:

```
<div ng-show="!!item.description && item.show_description">
    <div class="description-popup"
         style="left: {{item.x}}px; top: {{item.y}}px">
        <h2>{{item.label}}</h2>
        <p>{{item.description}}</p>
        <p>{{!!item.description && item.show_description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This assuming that the behaviour in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4822N/20/) is what you want.

This is probably only true for versions of Angular < 1.2. In 1.2, the behaviour of isolate scopes seems to have been cleaned up: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#isolate-scope-only-exposed-to-directives-with-scope-property

Comment: I've found that my code work on Angular 1.2 but not the versions before.

Comment: The JSFiddle you provided (and I changed), uses Angular 1.0.6. In my JSFiddle, the popup appears and disappears depending on where your mouse cursor is. Is that not what you intended?

Comment: Your code work but I don't think it have anything to do with isolated scope because on first element it work. and if ng-show would not have access to item it will not show at all, it will always return false.

Comment: My comment about version 1.2 was to my original code not yours. It work in that version so it's a bug in Angular, and your code somehow fixed the issue.

Comment: I thought isolate scopes still behaved like this after 1.2, but it seems I'm wrong about that. More info: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#isolate-scope-only-exposed-to-directives-with-scope-property